# most of keyboard not working

Tags: macos, keyboard

my MBP's keyboard has mostly stopped working.  esc to f12, tab, backspace, all arrow, meta(⌘ ⌥ ⌃), and shift work, noting else.  Caps lock won't even light.

Up until the word caps lock I was using the virtual keyboard.  It seems to come and go.  Any thoughts on why most of the keys don't work but not usually needed keys do?

It started with the E-O keys a few days ago and now its all character, number, and space keys.  Some how I feel its not a hardware problem...

Comment: Did you spill anything over your MBP?

Comment: As @patrix says, if it got wet somehow replacing is in order. Just to confirm your feeling it is not hardware run this hardware test from Apple http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14291  For software issues, try starting as different user or in Safe mode.

Comment: I haven't spilt anything on it and ran the extended Apple Hardware Test.  Test came back with no problems.  After doing an OS update it was acting fine for a while before it stopped working agin.